# How to configure Visual Studio 2022 to sign Git commits for GitHub using SSH or GPG keys?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I am having trouble configuring Visual Studio 2022 to sign Git commits for GitHub using SSH or GPG keys.

I tried setting up GPG signing using the following commands:

```
git config --global user.signingkey 3AA5C34371567BD2
git config --global commit.gpgsign true
```

However, when I try to make a commit in Visual Studio.

I get the following error:

```
Your Git hook is not supported. This is probably because the first line is not "#!/bin/sh".
```

I checked all the files in the `.git/hooks` directory and they all have `#!/bin/sh` as the first line.

If I don't set `git config --global commit.gpgsign true`, the commit goes through but on GitHub it is marked as unverified.

How can I properly configure Visual Studio to sign Git commits for GitHub using SSH or GPG keys? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

I found a solution for signing commits with SSH in Visual Studio 2022. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Edit the gitConfig file using the command `git config --global --edit`.
2. Add the following line: `[gpg "ssh"] sshCommand = C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe`.
3. Run the following commands:
   `git config --global gpg.format ssh`,
   `git config --global user.signingkey /C:/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_signinged25519.pub` and
   `git config --global commit.gpgsign true`.

Now, when I do a PUSH with Visual Studio, the commits have the verified label in GitHub.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check first if this is similar to [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-commit-failed-with-git-hook-error/139363), which, in 2019, added:

> Must run `git config --global gpg.program "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe"` command or the path where `gpg.exe` is installed.

Comment: This was the solution that resolved it working through Visual Studio 2022 commits for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure SSH Key is Added to GitHub:

Make sure that the SSH key you're using is added to your GitHub account. You can verify this by going to your GitHub account settings > SSH and GPG keys, and ensuring that your SSH key is listed there.
Check SSH Key Configuration:

Verify that the SSH key being used by Git matches the one added to your GitHub account. You can check the SSH key being used by running the following command:
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
This command will display the contents of your SSH public key. Make sure it matches the one listed in your GitHub account settings.

Add SSH Key to SSH Agent:
If you're using an SSH agent, make sure that your SSH key is added to the agent. You can add your SSH key to the agent by running the following command:
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Verify Remote URL:
Double-check that the remote URL for your Git repository is using SSH. You can verify this by running the following command:
git remote -v
Ensure that the URL starts with git@github.com: rather than https://github.com/.

Retry Push:
After ensuring that your SSH key is correctly configured and added to GitHub, try pushing your commits again using the SSH URL:
git push origin master

If you continue to encounter issues, double-check the error messages and ensure that your SSH key setup is correct.

Generate SSH Key:

Open a terminal or command prompt.

Run the following command to generate a new SSH key:
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
Replace "your_email@example.com" with the email address associated with your GitHub account.
Press Enter to accept the default file location (~/.ssh/id_rsa) or specify a different location if desired.
When prompted, optionally enter a passphrase to secure your SSH key.

Add SSH Key to SSH Agent (Optional):
If you're using an SSH agent, you can add your SSH key to the agent by running the following command:
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Add SSH Key to GitHub:
After generating the SSH key, you'll need to add it to your GitHub account.
Copy the contents of the public key (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) to your clipboard. You can use the cat command to display the contents and then copy them.
Go to your GitHub account settings > SSH and GPG keys.
Click on "New SSH key" or "Add SSH key."
Paste the copied SSH key into the "Key" field and give it a title (e.g., "My SSH Key").
Click "Add SSH key" to save the key to your GitHub account.

Verify SSH Key Setup:
After adding the SSH key to your GitHub account, you can verify that it's set up correctly by running the following command:
ssh -T git@github.com
If everything is set up correctly, you should see a message confirming that you've successfully authenticated.

Retry Push:
Once your SSH key is set up and associated with your GitHub account, try pushing your commits again using the SSH URL:
git push origin master

Comment: Hello, you can improve this answer with more formatting